# Non existence of a retraction

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The following example is given on page $14$ of Hatcher's Algebraic topology book without solution:

> Let $I=[0,1]$ and $A=\{ \frac {1}{n} : n \in \mathbb N\}$.Show that there is no continuous retraction $I^2 \to I \times \{0\} \cup A \times I$.

Basically above question shows that the pair $(I,A)$ does not have Homotopic extension property. How can we prove the above claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A$ given by Hatcher includes $0$, by the way.  If it were missing $0$, then we can use the comment right before: that if there were a retract $r$ and if $X$ is Hausdorff, then $A$ must be closed in $X$.  In this case, $X=I$ is Hausdorff, and $A$ is not closed in $I$.

With $0$ included, see [$I^2$ does not retract into comb space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/184285/172988)