# If a subspace $A$ is homotopy dominated by a finite polyhedron $X$, then is $A$ a retract of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

A subspace $A$ of a topological space $X$ is called a *retract* of $X$ if there exists a continuous map $r:X\to A$ such that $ri=\mathrm{id}_A$. Furthermore, a topological space $Y$ is *homotopy dominated* by  topological space $X$ if there exist continuous maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that $fg\simeq \mathrm{id}_Y$.

Question: Let $A$ be a subspace of a finite polyhedron $X$. If $A$ is homotopy dominated by $X$, then is $A$  a retract of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ be the unit square and let $A$ be the [comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space). Both $A$ and $X$ are contractible, so the inclusion $A\subseteq X$ is a homotopy equivalent. In particular $A$ is homotopy dominated by $X$. However, $A$ is [not a retract of $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184285/i2-does-not-retract-into-comb-space).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: In this case, $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$. Is there any example in which $A$ is homotopy dominated by $X$ but $X$ is not homotpy dominated by $A$?